# Entering and onFocus events are not triggered on Mac properly

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

hope somebody faced up with this issue and already know solution.

On Mac/Lotus Notes (I've version 9 installed).

On fields with 'Native OS Style' option enabled events 'Entering' and 'onFocus' are triggered only once (on first field I click) and then they never triggers again.

It works fine on Windows, however not on Mac.

Any ideas?

Comment: So, the event is on every field, but only executes the first time that a field is entered/focussed and never for any subsequent entry to any field? Could you post the code that executes in each? That way, we can see if there is something about that which causes a problem (such as filepaths, maybe).

Comment: @DavidNavarre, you are right. Here is the "msgbox 1". I came to conclusion it is an issue on Mac and changed UI so I do not use Native OS Style foe these fields anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to fix it, instead I've changed UI so we have no 'Native OS Style' fields anymore.